# python tkinter creating a widget outside his frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a widget outside his frame, but I don't know what's his master.

this is the structure.
first I created the class of the root. and then 3 classes of frames.
inside the class of the root I put a function. inside the function I created a text widget that should be located in the first one of the 3 frames

I really don't get what I should write as the master of my text widget to locate it in the first frame.

since I am a beginner if you have any advice I'd really appreciate.
thanks for attention here's the code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import datetime

LARGE_FONT = ("VERDANA", 12)


#user's information manager(classes and method)



class person:
    def __init__(self, name, birthday, sex):
        self.name = name
        self.birthday = birthday
        self.sex = sex

    def age(self, name, birthday):
        user = person(name, birthday, "male")
        today = datetime.date.today()

        print (today.year - self.birthday.year)




#main windows

class deathCalculatorapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "age calculator app")




        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)





        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

        # put all of the pages in the same location;
        # the one on the top of the stacking order
        # will be the one that is visible.
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")


# all methods here

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


    def calculate(self, name, birthday):
        user = person(name, birthday, "male")
        text_answer = tk.Text(master = , height=3, width=30)
        text_answer.grid(column=1, row=9)
        answear_text = ("{name} is {age} years    old".format(name=name_entry.get(), age=calculate()))
        text_answer.insert(tk.END, answear_text)
        print (user.age()


    #all of the frames

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller



    #Labels

    label = ttk.Label(self, text="deathcalculatorapp", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(column=1, row=0)

    first_label = ttk.Label(self, text = "insert your data")
    name_label= tk.Label(self, text = "name", bg="lightblue")
    year_label = tk.Label(self, text="year", bg ="lightblue", padx=9)
    month_label = tk.Label(self, text= "month", bg = "lightblue", padx=3)
    day_label = tk.Label(self, text ="day", bg= "lightblue", padx=11)

    first_label.grid(column=1, row=3)
    name_label.grid(column=0, row=4)
    year_label.grid(column=0, row =5)
    month_label.grid(column=0, row =6)
    day_label.grid(column=0, row = 7)




    #Entries

    name_entry = tk.Entry(self, text = "", bg = "lightblue")
    year_entry = tk.Entry(self,text = "", bg = "lightblue")
    month_entry = tk.Entry(self, text = "", bg= "lightblue")
    day_entry = tk.Entry(self, text= "", bg = "lightblue")



    name_entry.grid(column=1, row=4)
    year_entry.grid(column=1,row=5)
    month_entry.grid(column=1, row= 6)
    day_entry.grid(column=1, row=7)



    #Radiobutton about sex

    sexdatum = tk.IntVar()
    female= ttk.Radiobutton(self, text="female",variable= sexdatum, value="female")
    male=ttk.Radiobutton(self, text="male", variable= sexdatum, value="male")
    female.grid(column=2, row=4)
    male.grid(column=2, row=5)





    #Buttons

    calculate_button = ttk.Button(self, text="calculate your lifespawn",
                                  command=lambda: controller.age(name_entry.get(),datetime.date(int(year_entry.get()),int(month_entry.get()),int(day_entry.get()))))
    calculate_button.grid(column=1, row=8)
    button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
    button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
    button1.grid(column=0, row=0)
    button2.grid(column=0, row=1)



    #text



    #image

    image = Image.open(r"/"
                       r"Users/tommasomasaracchio/Documents/pythonfolder/kushina4.jpg")
    image.thumbnail((500,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    Photo_label= ttk.Label(self, image=photo)
    Photo_label.image = photo
    Photo_label.grid(row= 2, column = 1)






class PageOne(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    label = ttk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(column=0, row=0)
    button = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
    button.grid(column=0, row=0)


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    label = ttk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(column=0, row=0)
    button = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                       command=lambda:       controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.grid(column=0, row=0)






if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = deathCalculatorapp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please isolate your issue, prepare [mcve] for it, and provide it by pasting it here and then selecting it all and using `{}` or `Ctrl-K` to format it well.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `master = self.frames['StartPage']`.